# OpenCV : Open Mobotix Camera Feed

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a Mobotix Camera. It is an IP Camera. In the API they offer us the possibility to get the feed via

> http:// [**user**]:[**password**]@[**ip_adress**]:[**port**]/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg?[**options**]

---

What I've tried is to open it like a normal webcam feed :

```
cv::VideoCapture capture("http://...");
cv::Mat frame;

if (capture.isOpened())
    // always false anyway.
while(1)
{
    capture.read(frame);
    cv::imshow("Hi there", frame);
    cv::waitkey(10);
}
```

FYI : [Developer Mobotix API Docs](http://developer.mobotix.com/paks/help_cgi-image.html)

---

EDIT : Now thanks to [berak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2056772/berak) I just had to add &data=v.mjpg to the options :

```
?stream=full&fps=5.0&noaudio&data=v.mjpg
```

Note that in v.mjpg, only the [dot]mjpg is important, you could as well put myfile.mjpg.

Now the problem is the speed at which the feed update. I got a 2 seconds delay, plus the feed is very very slow. 
And when I change the stream option for MxJPG or mxg I get a corrupted image where the bytes aren't ordering properlly.

EDIT : I tried to change the camera parameters directly with the mobotix control center but only the resolution affected my OpenCV program, without actually changing the speed at which I access the images.

Comment: /cgi-bin/faststream.jpg sounds like a one-shot url,that sends 1 image only. please lookup alternative urls, that sound more like 'mjpeg' . also please check `capture.isOpened()`

Comment: Yeah, I tried to find alternative URLs, but I didn't find a single one. Plus, when I put the url in the browser I start downloading a jpeg that can't stop 'growing'.
And yeah, I always check isOpended(), and it's not.

Comment: cgi-bin/faststream.jpg?stream=full&fps=5&data=v.mjpg // the 'mjpg' at the end seems to to the trick

Comment: Nice one, it seems it does the trick, but now my problem is that with stream=full my program is very slow grabing the images.

Comment: stream=MxPEG; or similar ? also you can restrict the img size, jpg quality, etc.

Comment: I updated the question. The thing is with other stream format I get a corrupted image :(
And while I reduced the size and quality, only the browser capture displaying improved. The one with open CV didn't improve

Comment: I dont know if this might be helpful. You can write your code in two threads, one which uses windows api to read the stream and put those bytes in opencv mat container. The second thread read this stream whenever it is updated and uses opencv based processing that you require.

Comment: I would get it working single threaded first. Then look at threads and queues once you have the basics working

Comment: It seems the workaround of &data=v.mjpg no longer works :( - Anyone have another workaround?

Answer (score 0):

for max speed use fps=0  Its in the api docs

something like

```
http://cameraip/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg?stream=full&fps=0
```

see http://developer.mobotix.com/paks/help_cgi-image.html

faststream is the mjpeg stream (for image capture) , make sure mxpeg is turned off and pick the smallest image that gives you enough resolution. i.e get it working using 640 by 480 (set it camera webgui) then increase the image size.

Note this is for image capture not video and you need to detect the beginning and end of each jpeg then copy from receive buffer into memory.

vlc can handle mxpeg ,but need to either start from command line with vlc --ffmpeg-format=mxg or set an edit option ffmpeg-format=mxg in the gui
see https://wiki.videolan.org/MxPEG

Comment: Could you tell me how to detect the beginning & end of a jpeg in C++ ? I'm not sure I get what you're explaining.

Comment: A jpeg starts with 0xff , 0xd8 ,0xff , 0xe (0 or 1 - mobotix usually 0xe0) and ends with 0xff , 0xd9. Have a look at a jpeg in a hex editor. In your receive buffer you look for the first four then search for the end two (counting from the start position to the end position of jpeg) and then can copy the jpeg from the buffer (as you know the start position and length) and do what you want/need to, with it.

Comment: Also what user are you logging into the camera with from your application. Accessing the camera stream as a guest user is very slow(with default settings). Or in the camera web gui set the frame rate for guest access to maximum.

Comment: 2nd line of the OP http:// [user]:[password]@[ip_adress]:[port]/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg?[options]

I log in, that's why I wondered why it's so slow.
I will try your solution when I have time (I'm working two project at the time ^^)

Comment: check the acl (access control list) and see what the setting for your user is. Also using http:// [user]:[password]@[ip_adress]: ...   I never managed to get encoded passwords working. Putting "Get /cgi-bin/faststream.jpg?stream=full&fps=0 HTTP/1.0\nAuthorization: Basic xxxxx" where xxxx is the encoded password, does work for me.

Comment: make sure to use an admin user

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is quite old but I thought to answer for anyone else who comes across this issue. To get a stream without frame rate limitations you need to use a different CGI command:

```
http://<camera_IP>/control/faststream.jpg?stream=full&fps=0
```

As per the camera's on-line help:

```
http://<camera_IP>/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg (guest access)
http://<camera_IP>/control/faststream.jpg (user access)
```

The default limitation of the "guest" access is indeed 2 fps but it can be modified from the page Admin Menu > Language and Start Page.

A detailed description of how to retrieve a live stream from a MOBOTIX camera is available at the following link: https://community.mobotix.com/t/how-to-access-a-live-stream-with-a-video-client-e-g-vlc/202